# Configure access point on Ubuntu 20.04 with the wwan0 interface

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface, modem, netplan

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running on Raspberry Pi4 and have a 5G HAT to get it connected to the internet.

I have a `wwan0` network interface with the IP. Now I'd like to make this network available as an access point to other devices. I tried to use a netplan, but it seems to work only with `eth0` interface. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: hm, netplan works with any interface name, so that's probably not the problem! But I'm not sure you'd need netplan for this at all? We don't really know what you've been trying, would you mind explaining that? It might also be useful to know what kind of WLAN network interface you're using!

Comment: sure, i'm using SIM8200EA-M2_5G_HAT as a network interface, it have been configured as wwan0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500. in netplan yaml i was trying to define it in this way: network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    wwan0:
      dhcp4: true
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: true
       access-points:
        "Raspberry":
          password: "password"
          mode: ap

Answer (score 1):

To configure an access point on Ubuntu install the [`linux-wifi-hotspot`](https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lakinduakash/lwh
sudo apt install linux-wifi-hotspot
```

To use the GUI: `wihotspot`.

To Use the CLI `create_ap --help` [see create_ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap).

To get the same subnet:

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap.git
cd create_ap/
```

Edit `create_ap.conf`, `nano create_ap.conf`:

```
CHANNEL=default
GATEWAY=100.105.160.1 # set your gateway
WPA_VERSION=2
ETC_HOSTS=0
DHCP_DNS=gateway
NO_DNS=0
NO_DNSMASQ=0
HIDDEN=0
MAC_FILTER=0
MAC_FILTER_ACCEPT=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.accept
ISOLATE_CLIENTS=0
SHARE_METHOD=nat
IEEE80211N=0
IEEE80211AC=0
HT_CAPAB=[HT40+]
VHT_CAPAB=
DRIVER=nl80211
NO_VIRT=0
COUNTRY=
FREQ_BAND=2.4
NEW_MACADDR=
DAEMONIZE=0
NO_HAVEGED=0
WIFI_IFACE=wlan0
INTERNET_IFACE=wwan0 # set the connected interface
SSID=MyAccessPoint # set your AP name 
PASSPHRASE=12345678 # set your passphrase here
USE_PSK=0
```

Then run:

```
sudo ./create_ap --config create_ap.conf
```

Also, you can use the `-g` option to set the gateway:

```
sudo bash create_ap -g 100.105.160.1 wlan0 wwan0 AP PASS
```

Comment: should i stop it somehow, or it-s just enaugh to run the commands: sed -i 's/GATEWAY.*/GATEWAY=192.105.160.1/' create_ap.conf
sudo ./create_ap options_here can i ask you where you get the Gateway ip? should i put the one assigned to wwan0?

Comment: with the Gateway you mean the wwan0 address? than it is 100.105.160.234, if so i tried the command suggested by you, but it didn-t change a lot, i still have a wlan0 192.XX.XX.X and i can-t even ping the RPi IP from my PC, which is connected through the AP and seems to not have an internet connection. even worse, the RPi loose the DNS server settings when i initialize the AP.

Comment: i can see the config file exactly as u updated. But once i run the create_up command the DNS server setting are getting ruined for some reason.

Comment: yes, it didn-t hep `Configuration file: /tmp/create_ap.wlan0.conf.RpdqsTUV/hostapd.conf
wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr dc:a6:32:bd:08:52 and ssid "PiT"
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
wlan0: AP-ENABLED 
wlan0: STA 38:d5:7a:37:54:8b IEEE 802.11: associated
wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 38:d5:7a:37:54:8b
wlan0: STA 38:d5:7a:37:54:8b RADIUS: starting accounting session 75AABD64579AF4B8
wlan0: STA 38:d5:7a:37:54:8b WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (WPA)
wlan0: STA 38:d5:7a:37:54:8b WPA: group key handshake completed (WPA)`

Comment: if this log could help somehow

Comment: eacon_int=100
ssid=PiT
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
channel=1
ctrl_interface=/tmp/create_ap.wlan0.conf.h0IrYPG3/hostapd_ctrl
ctrl_interface_group=0
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
ap_isolate=0
hw_mode=g
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=12345678
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
how should i change it?

Comment: ok, i found the root cause. it was an dnsmasq.config. I changed there listen-address=100.105.160.234
bind-dynamic
dhcp-range=100.105.160.1,100.105.160.254,255.255.255.0,24h
dhcp-option-force=option:router,100.105.160.234
dhcp-option-force=option:dns-server,8.8.8.8
dhcp-option-force=option:mtu,1500
no-hosts
: the line 5, where dns server is defined, it was pointing to his own IP, and was not able to resolve any address, changing it to 8.8.8.8 now i can access internet from both RPi4 and from the connected device. My question is how i can make this happen automatically on script run?

Comment: @LiudmilaDobriakova There are some options if you run `./create_ap --help`. the dnsmasq can be disabled by `--no-dnsmasq` The DNS can be set by `--dhcp-dns` option.

Comment: doesn't seem to work. Even if I force the dns server it can't resolve the domain name.